# Does clicking the back button calls applicationWillTerminate method in IOS?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, reload, lifecycle

Im just curious to know whether the **applicationWillTerminate()** method is being called when back button is clicked in IOS. So now, i have this `WKWebView` in my ios app that loads a smart chat url. This chat bot is used by users if they have any questions regarding how to use the app. What im trying to achieve is that, when the user clicks the back button and goes away from the UI controller that has the `WKWebView` in it, the previous conversation of the user with the chatbot is not saved. However, if the home button is clicked from the `WKWebView` and the user goes back into the app the conversation remains there. How do i prevent the UI controller that has the `WKWebView` from being reloaded if the back button is clicked?

Answer (score 2):

Do that in `applicationWillResignActive`.

If you only click the home button , APP is not being terminated. It still lives in the background so that `applicationWillTerminate` is not called.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But do you know will the ```applicationWillTerminate``` method will be called if back button is clicked?

Comment: nope when we click back button applicationWillTerminate is not called @rana

Comment: @SiddhantNigam thanks for the answer. But do u know why the ```WKWebview``` is being reloaded when back button is clicked? Does this mean if the UI controller enters the background state, and wants to go back into the foreground state it gets reloaded?

Comment: I think it depends on when you call webView.load(). If you call in viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear, it will get reloaded. I don't think it will get reloaded in other ways. @rana

Answer (score 1):

ok firstly why applicationWillTerminate will gets called on back button this is just to pop viewcontroller until you explicitly exit app. Secondly you should check how to clear you chatbot current session so whenever you click back or on viewdiddisappear you will make chatbot session clear so conversation does n't get saved. I think whatever chatbot you are using they are caching conversation until you logout from session or perform some cleanup.

-- Updated ----
use following as WKWebview parent class in custom class section uistoryboard

```
import Foundation
import WebKit

class WKCookieWebView : WKWebView {

    private let useRedirectCookieHandling: Bool

    init(frame: CGRect, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, useRedirectCookieHandling: Bool = false) {
        self.useRedirectCookieHandling = useRedirectCookieHandling
        configuration.applicationNameForUserAgent = "Version/8.0.2 Safari/600.2.5"
        super.init(frame: frame, configuration: configuration)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        self.useRedirectCookieHandling = false
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    override func load(_ request: URLRequest) -> WKNavigation? {
        guard useRedirectCookieHandling else {
            return super.load(request)
        }

        requestWithCookieHandling(request, success: { (newRequest , response, data) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.syncCookiesInJS()
                if let data = data, let response = response {
                    let _ = self.webViewLoad(data: data, response: response)
                } else {
                    self.syncCookies(newRequest, nil, { (cookieRequest) in
                        let _ = super.load(cookieRequest)
                    })
                }
            }
        }, failure: {
            // let WKWebView handle the network error
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.syncCookies(request, nil, { (newRequest) in
                    let _ = super.load(newRequest)
                })
            }
        })

        return nil
    }

    private func requestWithCookieHandling(_ request: URLRequest, success: @escaping (URLRequest, HTTPURLResponse?, Data?) -> Void, failure: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if let _ = error {
                failure()
            } else {
                if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {

                    let code = response.statusCode
                    if code == 200 {
                        // for code 200 return data to load data directly
                        success(request, response, data)

                    } else if code >= 300 && code <  400  {
                        // for redirect get location in header,and make a new URLRequest
                        guard let location = response.allHeaderFields["Location"] as? String, let redirectURL = URL(string: location) else {
                            failure()
                            return
                        }

                        let request = URLRequest(url: redirectURL, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 5)
                        success(request, nil, nil)

                    } else {
                        success(request, response, data)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    private func webViewLoad(data: Data, response: URLResponse) -> WKNavigation! {
        guard let url = response.url else {
            return nil
        }

        let encode = response.textEncodingName ?? "utf8"
        let mine = response.mimeType ?? "text/html"

        return self.load(data, mimeType: mine, characterEncodingName: encode, baseURL: url)
    }
}

extension WKCookieWebView {
    // sync HTTPCookieStorage cookies to URLRequest
    private func syncCookies(_ request: URLRequest, _ task: URLSessionTask? = nil, _ completion: @escaping (URLRequest) -> Void) {
        var request = request
        var cookiesArray = [HTTPCookie]()

        if let task = task {
            HTTPCookieStorage.shared.getCookiesFor(task, completionHandler: { (cookies) in
                if let cookies = cookies {
                    cookiesArray.append(contentsOf: cookies)

                    let cookieDict = HTTPCookie.requestHeaderFields(with: cookiesArray)
                    if let cookieStr = cookieDict["Cookie"] {
                        request.addValue(cookieStr, forHTTPHeaderField: "Cookie")
                    }
                }
                completion(request)
            })
        } else  if let url = request.url {
            if let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies(for: url) {
                cookiesArray.append(contentsOf: cookies)
            }
            let cookieDict = HTTPCookie.requestHeaderFields(with: cookiesArray)
            if let cookieStr = cookieDict["Cookie"] {
                request.addValue(cookieStr, forHTTPHeaderField: "Cookie")
            }
            completion(request)

        } else {
            if let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies {
                cookiesArray.append(contentsOf: cookies)
            }
            let cookieDict = HTTPCookie.requestHeaderFields(with: cookiesArray)
            if let cookieStr = cookieDict["Cookie"] {
                request.addValue(cookieStr, forHTTPHeaderField: "Cookie")
            }
            completion(request)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - JS Cookie handling
    private func syncCookiesInJS(for request: URLRequest? = nil) {
        if let url = request?.url,
            let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies(for: url) {
            let script = jsCookiesString(for: cookies)
            let cookieScript = WKUserScript(source: script, injectionTime: .atDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: false)
            self.configuration.userContentController.addUserScript(cookieScript)

        } else if let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies {
            let script = jsCookiesString(for: cookies)
            let cookieScript = WKUserScript(source: script, injectionTime: .atDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: false)
            self.configuration.userContentController.addUserScript(cookieScript)
        }
    }

    private func jsCookiesString(for cookies: [HTTPCookie]) -> String {
        var result = ""
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"

        for cookie in cookies {
            result += "document.cookie='\(cookie.name)=\(cookie.value); domain=\(cookie.domain); path=\(cookie.path); "
            if let date = cookie.expiresDate {
                result += "expires=\(dateFormatter.string(from: date)); "
            }
            if (cookie.isSecure) {
                result += "secure; "
            }
            result += "'; "
        }
        return result
    }
}

extension WKCookieWebView : URLSessionTaskDelegate {

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, willPerformHTTPRedirection response: HTTPURLResponse, newRequest request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping (URLRequest?) -> Void) {

        syncCookies(request) { (newRequest) in
            completionHandler(newRequest)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Sadly the chat bot im using is not saving any session. Hence, i need to do it manually. When i click home button and return back to the app, the conversation is still there. However, if i click the back button the conversation is being cleared. Im trying to figure out now, how to prevent the ```WKWebView``` from being reloaded when the back button is clicked.

Comment: ok got that let me share class with you for that purpose that can help you

Comment: thanks for your time and answer. But it still didnt work for me. When i click back and return back to the ```WKWebView``` it still gets reloaded and the previous conversation disappear.

Comment: can you share your source??